# Amplify.Storage: Is there a way to list only the files in my bucket?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am trying to list all the files in my bucket via:

```
Amplify.Storage.list("",
    result -> {
        for (StorageItem item : result.getItems()) {
            Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "File: " + item.getKey() + ", Hash: " + item.getETag());
        }
    },
    error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "List failure", error)
);
```

But I am only interested in files, not directories. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a definite solution to my problem. Here is the closest solution I wrote:

```
Amplify.Storage.list("",
    result -> {
        for (StorageItem item : result.getItems()) {
            if(item.getSize() == 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "File is empty, skip: " + item.getKey());
                continue;
            }
            Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "File: " + item.getKey() + ", Hash: " + item.getETag());
        }
    }
    error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "List failure", error)
);
```

This simply ignores any `StorageItem` that is zero bytes in size. This works in my case because aside from directories, I am also not interested in empty files.